# Weird error while using externaldata operator in kusto query

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to load the AWS ip ranges from their provided API as seen in the query below. If I use the proper url "https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json", I get the error message shown below. But if I run the same query for the json hosted at my own url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anandmudgerikar/aws-ips/main/ip-ranges.json", the query works fine. Any idea what might be happening? Thanks in advance.

Kusto Query:

```
externaldata(syncToken:string, createDate:string, prefixes: dynamic , ipv6_prefixes: dynamic)
[ 
    h@'https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json'
    //h@'https://api.github.com/users/anandmudgerikar/repos'
    // h@'https://reqres.in/api/product/3'
    //h@'https://www.dropbox.com/s/24117ufuyfanmew/ip-ranges.json'
    //h@'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anandmudgerikar/aws-ips/main/ip-ranges.json'
]
with(format= 'multijson', ingestionMapping=
'[{"Column":"syncToken","Properties":{"Path":"$.syncToken"}},' 
'{"Column":"createDate","Properties":{"Path":"$.createDate"}},' 
'{"Column":"prefixes","Properties":{"Path":"$.prefixes"}},'
'{"Column":"ipv6_prefixes","Properties":{"Path":"$.ipv6_prefixes"}}]')
```

This is the error message I get:

```
Query execution has resulted in error (0x80004003): Partial query failure: Invalid pointer (message: 'Argument 'name' is null: at .ctor in C:\source\Src\Common\Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Azure\Storage\PersistentStorage\BlobPersistentStorageFile.cs: line 55
Parameter name: name: ', details: 'Source: Kusto.Cloud.Platform
System.ArgumentNullException: Argument 'name' is null: at .ctor in C:\source\Src\Common\Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Azure\Storage\PersistentStorage\BlobPersistentStorageFile.cs: line 55
Parameter name: name
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Utils.Ensure.FailNullOrEmpty(String value, String argName, String callerMemberName, String callerFilePath, Int32 callerLineNumber) in C:\source\Src\Common\Kusto.Cloud.Platform\Diagnostics\Ensure.cs:line 150
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Azure.Storage.PersistentStorage.BlobPersistentStorageFile..ctor(CloudBlobContainer blobContainer, String name, IPersistentStorageFileCompressor persistentStorageFileCompressor, IPersistentStorageUri persistentStorageUri, TriState validBlobStorage, FileKnownMetadata knownMetadata) in C:\source\Src\Common\Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Azure\Storage\PersistentStorage\BlobPersistentStorageFile.cs:line 56
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Azure.Storage.PersistentStorage.BlobPersistentStorageFactory.CreateFileRef(String uri, IKustoTokenCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider, String compressionType, IPersistentStorageFileCompressorFactory persistentStorageFileCompressorFactory, StorageItemLocationMode locationMode, FileKnownMetadata knownMetadata) in C:\source\Src\Common\Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Azure\Storage\PersistentStorage\BlobPersistentStorageFactory.cs:line 214
   at Kusto.Cloud.Platform.Storage.PersistentStorage.PersistentStorageFactoryFactory.CreateFileRef(String uri, IKustoTokenCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider, String compressionType, IPersistentStorageFileCompressorFactory persistentStorageFileCompressorFactory, StorageItemLocationMode locationMode, FileKnownMetadata knownMetadata) in C:\source\Src\Common\Kusto.Cloud.Platform\Storage\PersistentStorage\PersistentStorageFactoryFactory.cs:line 154
   at Kusto.DataNode.DataEngineQueryPlan.ExternalDataQueryUtils.ReadExternalDataAsCsv(ArtifactEntry artifactEntry, DataSourceStreamFormat format, ExternalDataQueryCallbackContext callbackContext, Int64 recordCountLimit, String& columnsMapping) in C:\source\Src\Engine\DataNode\QueryService\DataEngineQueryPlan\ExternalDataQueryUtils.cs:line 101
   at Kusto.DataNode.DataEngineQueryPlan.DataEngineQueryProcessor.DataEngineQueryCallback.GetExternalData(String externalDataUri, DataSourceStreamFormat format, String serializedCallbackContext, Int64 recordCountLimit) in C:\source\Src\Engine\DataNode\QueryService\DataEngineQueryPlan\DataEngineQueryProcessor.cs:line 399').
 clientRequestId: KustoWebV2;71c590e6-27ab-41c9-bf3c-03ba4ee0cf3b
```

Answer (score 0):

Only storage connection strings that are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage) are officially supported; There are no guarantees for others.

To comply with that, for example, you can copy the file from its original location to an Azure blob container, and query it from there.

Comment: Yes, the problem with that is that since this file is updated almost daily by AWS, it would need to be copied every day to the azure blob container. Is there no other way to access the external URL?